# Change of JS State Variable in Googlemaps API Geocoder does not work

Tags: javascript, variables, google-maps-api-3, state, google-geocoder

Hello smarter than me people. ;)
I really cannot figure this weird behaviour of my code out.

What it is supposed to do is to execute the function fixedlocation() when a button is pressed in order to check if a valid address can be found and then execute some code.

In order to check if it works properly I have an alert in the code which gives me the state of the Boolean that should be changed. Now I really dont get why, but it only works from the second time the button is pressed onwards. Meaning that even if a valid address can be found, the first time the alert will pop up with a false...

At first I thought it must have something to do with where I defined the variable but then it couldnt work the second time could it?

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated.

```
var geoinfobool=new Boolean();
function fixedlocation()
{    

    var addresscoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById('addresslat').value,document.getElementById('addresslng').value)
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': addresscoordinates}, function(results, status) 
    {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
            geoinfoavailable(true);

            //do other stuff in here//

        } 
        else 
        {
            geoinfoavailable(false);

            //do other stuff in here//

        }
    });

    alert(geoinfobool);
}

function geoinfoavailable(state)

{
    geoinfobool = state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code geocoder is not defined .

Try

```
var addresscoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById('addresslat').value,document.getElementById('addresslng').value);
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': addresscoordinates}, function(results, status) 
{
```

Comment: Thanks for the input david, I actually have the geocoder defined, did not post it properly sorry. I am more confused than ever after I found out that I get the correct alert if I include the alert within the code of the geocorder. If the alert(geoinfobool); follows right after the closing brackets of the else then it suddenly works... Really dont have a clue why that would be the case though...